# Error when running powershell script to import users from csv using Import-Csv and New-QADUser into Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008, powergui

My script looks like this:

```
$Users = Import-Csv "C:\users.csv"
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    New-QADUser -Name $User.Name `
        -ParentContainer $User.OU `
        -FirstName $User.FirstName `
        -LastName $User.LastName `
        -UserPassword $User.userPassword `
        -SamAccountName $User.sAMAccountName `
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
DefaultNamingContext                               Type            
--------------------                               ----            
DC=example,DC=domain,DC=org                  ActiveDirectory 
The server is unwilling to process the request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072035)
At :line:5 char:12
+   New-QADUser <<<<  -Name $User.Name `
```

My CSV looks like this:

```
Name,FirstName,LastName,sAMAccountName,UserPassword,OU
Joe Bob,Joe,Bob,jb241277,4gh60b4,"OU=2010,OU=Sub,OU=Users,OU=MAIN,DC=example,DC=domain,DC=org"
```

Not sure what is going on, any help would be appreciated.  This is a child domain in a forest on Win2K8 Ent.

Comment: You might try asking this question on http://serverfault.com which is aimed more at admin type questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this action is being attempted against a Global Catalog for some reason. Your code works fine for me, but I get the error when I attempt to do it against a GC, which is expected. The `connect-QADService` cmdlet specifies where you want to connect. If you're setting this before your new-qaduser code, double-check to make sure that "-UseGlobalCatalog" is not in there.

As a troubleshooting step you can try to specify a specific Domain Controller to see if that changes your error.

```
$Users = Import-Csv "C:\users.csv"
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    New-QADUser -Name $User.Name `
        -ParentContainer $User.OU `
        -FirstName $User.FirstName `
        -LastName $User.LastName `
        -UserPassword $User.userPassword `
        -SamAccountName $User.sAMAccountName `
        -Service $DomainController `
}
```

That will tell it to perform the action against a specific domain controller and not a Global Catalog.